# Jest coverage - if statement in switch statement

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, code-coverage

I am trying to achieve 100% test coverage and can't seem to pin down why this code isn't being covered with the tests I have

code:

```
    case "Premier":
        {
            if(usagePercentage !== '100%'){
                return (
                    <div className='messageText__paid'>
                        <p className='messageText__paid__revenueGenerated'>Revenue generated this cycle: ${revenue}</p>
                        <p className='messageText__paid__review'>Love boop? <a href=''>Leave a review</a></p>
                    </div>
                    )
            }
            if(usagePercentage === '100%'){
                return (
                    <div className='messageText__paid__limitCap'>
                        <p>You’ve hit your usage cap for your current plan, contact us</p>
                    </div>
                    )
            }
        }
```

test:

```
let generatedMessage = shallow(generateMessage('Premier', 1756.11, '100%'))

        it('should generate the plan cap warning', () => {
            expect(generatedMessage.hasClass('messageText__paid__limitCap')).toEqual(true)
        })
        let generatedMessage = shallow(generateMessage('Premier', 1756.11, '55%'))

        it('should generate the paid plan message', () => {
            expect(generatedMessage.hasClass('messageText__paid')).toEqual(true)
        })
```

Comment: The test you posted is only covering the second `if` - do you have more tests?

Comment: Ah sorry I have included that test as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you also need to test the first branch in your statement; what something happens if `useagePercentage` is not 100%.

Something like this:

```
let otherGeneratedMessage = shallow(generateMessage('Premier', 1756.11, '50%'))

    it('should generate revenue cycle message', () => {
        expect(otherGeneratedMessage.hasClass('messageText__paid')).toEqual(true)
    })
```

Comment: Ah sorry I updated the question with the other test that I already have which includes the first if statement